# Subtract NumOfDays to Given Date to Get PreComputed Date exclude Sundays on Count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem regarding this

```
Date : 09/30/2014
NumOfDays : 5
Expected PreComputed Date : 09/24/2014

----------------------------
09/29/2014            Day 1
09/28/2014(Sunday)    Skip
09/27/2014            Day 2
09/26/2014            Day 3
09/25/2014            Day 4
09/24/2014            Day 5 ---> PrecComputed Date
```

I need to get the Precomputed Date Excluding Sundays on Count
Using Javascript or Jquery
on this format `mm/dd/yyyy`

Comment: What code have you written yourself to attempt to solve this problem?

Comment: please add the code or elaborate

Comment: I dont have codes yet, :(

Comment: Just the logic i know but i cant find a code for it

Comment: @Rory McCrossan like on this www.timeanddate.com/date/weekdaysubtract.html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I dont have the codes Just the logic i know but i cant find a code for it... i saw an web app similar on this like on this www.timeanddate.com/date/weekdaysubtract.html

Comment: @N.M.N I dont have the codes Just the logic i know but i cant find a code for it... i saw an web app similar on this like on this www.timeanddate.com/date/weekdaysubtract.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is spoon feeding but you can iterate the date and check whether there is sunday in any date or not.

```js
function isSunday(date){

   return date.getDay()==0;

}


function getPreComputedDate(date1,marginToBeCalc){
   var preComputedDate = new Date(date1);

   preComputedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
   for(var i=1;i<=marginToBeCalc-1;i++){
 if(isSunday(preComputedDate)){
            i--;
 } 
preComputedDate=addDaysToDate(preComputedDate,1);
   }
   alert(preComputedDate);
   return preComputedDate;
}

function addDaysToDate(date,incrementValue){
   var tempDate=new Date(date);
   return new Date(tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + incrementValue));
}
```

```html
 <a href="#" onclick="getPreComputedDate('09/07/2014',15)">Get Date</a>
```

Comment: Bro. I only need input the Date and Numof Days, to get the PreComputed Date.

Comment: Then that would be really simple without using 2 date.

Comment: @BenjieJunio please check my updated answer. And accept the answer if you are satisfied